# Google Doc comments: Can I replicate the "+" autocompletion behavior using Apps Scrip?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I would like to have a functionality similar to the "+" character on Google Docs Comments, which opens a dropdown menu with autocompletion options (in this case, Google Users). In my case, I would like to offer suggestions when the user types another character, let's say "#".

I have searched for "autocompletion" functionalities in the Apps Script context but the only documentation available is about the code editor.

Any tips will be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible, as the scripts get executed once the user has completed the changes and the Doc is saved. 
 Also, creating a comment and "assigning" it to a user using "+" is not possible from the API, It's a feature that has been [requested](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756650) already.

Comment: Hey @Jescanellas. Thanks for the help. I did not get though the relevance of your first comment on when scripts get executed. (I might need to clarify myself:) I am not interested in assigning the user, I only want to emulate the dropdown menu when the user types the special character. So, I guess the feature you pointed to is not related to my problem. I am actually confident I can create the functionality if I create a whole plug-in, but this would basically recreate the commenting box for a selected text. =/